# Why is there no combadge lag on initiating inter-personnel comms?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

This has always bothered me- When initiating an inter-personal conversation in Star Trek it is common to use the form "[my name] to [their name]" potentially immediately followed by a question. Although I cannot back this up at present, I am sure we have seen many instances where the called party responds instantly.

However, whilst the routing system will know *your* name, it won't know the name of the recipient until you have completed saying their name in the opening sentance. Then and only then can it locate the target and open the communications. Not only that, it will then have to relay your opening statement so the recipient knows who is calling them. And only after having listened to it can they reply with "[Their name] here Captain" or somesuch...

Of course this would be solved if every statement to open comms was a broadcast to all possible recipients, but I have seen no evidence for that being the case...

Are there any explanations for this apparent communications miracle?

Comment: makes the production cheaper / episode shorter. ;-P

Comment: The software is sufficiently good, and fast enough, to decipher the recipient and begin transmitting the communication before the message is complete. The only lag necessary is the time it takes the sender to say the name of the receiver. This is assuming they are not communicating to a broadcast channel, say for "Away Team A".

Comment: @Gorchestopher - Not so, the maximum lag duration is the point at which the sender begins talking, to the point the system is able to identify the recipient, which could easily be at least one second. And as I say, once it has identified the recipient it needs to send the name of the calling party, which the recipient has to listen to, before the recipient can reply... In fact I am certain we hear, from the recipients point of view, the entire opening statement, e.g. "Picard to Riker", and then Riker responds... So the lag would be approx 2x the duration of "Picard to Riker"...

Comment: @Marv Mills -- why do you say 2x? As soon as Picard stops saying "Picard to Riker" and starts the first words of the message, Riker then begins to hear "Picard to Riker" as Picard is saying the first words, then Riker begins to hear Picard's first words. So the delay should only be the length of that single "Picard to Riker".

Comment: @MarvMills The time lag is from when the sender begins talking to when the sender says the name of the recipient. For all intents and purposes the software identifying the recipient is *really* good and fast.

Comment: Pure speculation, but since they have universal translators that re-interpret a person's *intended meaning* so that it can be understood, is it not also possible that they have comm badges that can tell exactly who you want to contact the moment you tap them?

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, just the 1x "Picard to Riker" - let's say that takes one second to say. Once I have said it, Riker receives it and spends 1 second listening before replying, and as the channel is open I hear his response immediately. That is still an appreciable delay and I'm sure in some cases there is quite a speech before the sender finally says the name of the recipient...

Comment: @Hypnosifl: often (if I’m remembering correctly), Picard will tap the comm badge and say “Picard to Riker”, and Riker will almost immediately reply with “Yes captain”, seemingly before Picard’s original message of “Picard to Riker” could have been replayed to him.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite - That is exactly the effect I have clumsily tried to point out :)

Comment: Probably the writers didn't think about this but you could always make up a reasonable explanation, like maybe Riker just hears "Picard" rather than "Picard to Riker" (maybe he even hears a sped-up chipmunk version!), or maybe Riker has a default "yes captain" message that plays whenever Picard contacts him (and the communicator detects that he's not asleep or something), so Picard is hearing the recording while Riker is hearing "Picard to Riker".

Comment: Not at all Marv, you nailed it.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: that would make sense, but I think at times we also hear incoming messages (e.g. we see Riker hearing “Picard to Riker” and replying “Yes captain”), with no apparent sped-up version or auto-replies. (I haven’t got video references for any of this though.)

Comment: We actually see this to an even greater extent in one of the early VOY episodes. (I forgot which.) Kim: "I've never seen anything like it!" Tuvok (taps his com badge): "Tuvok to Kim. Mr Kim, that is an expression we prefer to not hear from a senior officer on the bridge." In this case, they are both at their respective stations on the bridge, and are both in camera view, so we see Tuvok speaking as we hear the audio in real time supposedly through Kim's com badge.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite - you're right, I searched the transcripts site chakoteya.net by entering "site:www.chakoteya.net/NextGen" into google along with the search phrase in quotation marks "[OC]: Picard to" and found a bunch of examples where we here Picard calling someone off-camera and see them responding. And if you just use the phrase "Picard to" to search the transcripts on that site, you can also find plenty of examples where you see Picard calling someone on camera and hear them responding off-camera.

Comment: @Michael Kjörling - I searched site:www.chakoteya.net/voyager and found the exchange you're talking about, it's from the episode "The Cloud". Here are the exact words, would have to see the episode to check whether it's clear that Kim actually heard the words "Tuvok to Kim" in realtime-- KIM: I've never seen anything like it. (Tuvok uses his comm. badge.) TUVOK: Tuvok to Kim. Mister Kim, that is a comment we'd prefer not to hear from a senior officer on the Bridge. It makes the junior officers nervous.

Comment: @Michael Kjörling - I saw that the "The Cloud" is available on amazon streaming at http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B005HEWO6W/ref=dv_dp_ep5 so I watched the beginning, the scene is a little over 9 minutes in. Kim looks over at Tuvok immediately after Tuvok hits his combadge and says "Tuvok to Kim", and from the way his voice sounds, it seems that we're hearing his voice over Kim's combadge rather than Tuvok's actual voice carrying over to Kim from the other side of the bridge. Maybe the combadges monitor anticipatory activity in the brain and can predict whose name a person will call!

Comment: Another possibility is that the scene in "The Cloud" is using a sort of borderline non-diegetic sound (see http://www.screenplayology.com/content-sections/screenplay-form-content/3-7/#topic1 ), meaning that we in the audience are hearing Tuvok's message slightly before Harry hears it...Harry only turns his head after we hear Tuvok say "Tuvok to Kim", so it's possible he's actually just beginning to hear him say "Tuvok" at that moment.

Comment: @Hypnosifl: nice, proper research.

Comment: In some cases the system will be able to use optimisations based on context.  For example in Voyager, messages from Ensign Kim to Capt. Janeway will **not** be recorded but will be replaced by the most likely pre-recorded phrases from a large database.  In order of frequency (most common first) the first three are as follows: "I'm sorry Captain, it won't happen again.", "I don't know what I did wrong." and "It's some kind of multiphasic, trilateral, tetrion field with unstable warp matrix.".

Comment: "Modern Technology, William!" - Rufus.  (In other words, Artistic Licence)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [TNG Technical Manual](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Technical_Manual) addresses precisely this issue. In short, the computer AI is smart enough to route your communication directly to the person you're addressing. As soon as they acknowledge the communication (by replying or tapping the button), the rest of the conversation is realtime. Any delay is either not shown or is simply too short to be noticeable.

The exception to this would be on away missions when the channel is "left open" in which case two-way communication seems to take place automatically...

[image]

Comment: Clearly the actual answer, so marked as such, but it just avoids the issue really as it is not logically possible to make the conversation real time immediately following the computer hearing the "entire name of the recipient and located same" for the reasons discussed in the OP and witnessed when observing a recipient hearing the full opening message and responding immediately. Thanks for the post.

Comment: @MarvMills - out-of-universe, I think the last part of Paul's answer is right. The delay is simply edited out of the conversation (e.g. unless the delay in responding is part of the plotline).

Comment: Out of universe there is no delay to edit, it's just actors without a communication system! :)

Comment: They "edit it out" by not filming it :P

Answer (score 19):

Here's how it would work:

- User taps combadge / panel etc.
- Computer plays acknowledgement tone, begins recording.
- User says "Picard to Riker"

  - computer already knows who the speaker is, recognizes "to" and likely has the recipient identified by the second syllable.
  - computer continues recording
- Computer opens channel to recipient, plays the announcement.
- As soon as the recipient taps their badge or verbally acknowledges the communication, the rest of the recording comes through. The conversation will sync itself up rather quickly. Neither party knows (or cares) that there's a delay equal to the recipient's response time.

This is not much different than "Siri, tell my wife I will be 30 minutes late", just improved by 3 centuries of progress and a processor *far* in advance of what we have now.

Any annoying delays are edited out in post-production. It's still TV, after all.

Comment: "It's still TV, after all"... Sacrilege! :)

Comment: Agreed @Paul - we already have technology almost this good now. It's not difficult to imagine that in 300 years or less, instantaneous communication will be possible. I'd be surprised if something similar isn't commonplace in less than 50 years.

Comment: The TNG manual says that the "button tap" is unnecessary when you're on the ship.

Comment: @Omegacron there will always be a time delay caused, the speed of light dictates the minimum delay between a signal being sent and received after all.

Comment: The delay could be used for buffering, or the old audio played slightly sped up to catch up. A 2 second delay might be critical in some cases like springing a trap. IRL, radio and [WebRTC](http://www.webrtc.org/) already provide realtime comms.

Comment: I like how people try to apply current physics understanding to sci-fi. It's sci-fi, and you can invent anything like subspace to do what you want. And IRL, for all we know, things like entanglement could turn out to have aspects that allow for practical applications.

Comment: @JamesChristopher : With a lot of sci-fi, I would agree. Star Trek, however, has generally tried to ground itself within the realm of scientific possibility. Most kinds of technology used in the show are based on theories that exist now. Obviously, they have to take dramatic license from time to time, but I would say 75% of what we see in the show (at least, technology-wise) will be reality at some point.

Comment: @Omegacron - Warp Drive in ST is not based on existing theory... it isn't at all the same as the warp drive theory that NASA has talked about. What theoretical base do transporters have, as well?

Comment: @Omegacron: the theoretical base that transporters have dates back to 1905: that matter and energy are interchangeable. Converting the rest-mass energy of a 100kg human into energy and reassembling it somewhere else just requires decent engineering. You'll want to be on the other side of the continent during the first tests.

Comment: @paul - Converting 100Kg to energy would be the equivalent of around 215000 megatonnes of explosive force. You'd probably want to be on the next planet, not the next continent. http://www.jick.net/~jess/hr/skept/EMC2/node4.html

Comment: My math was 2.1Gt equivalent, or 140 times that of Castle Bravo / 42 x Tzar Bomba. Certainly enough to detach Florida but Alaska should be safe enough.

Comment: @JamesChristopher Whilst I agree with you, the problem I have pointed out here is not a technological issue, it is a logical issue- nothing to do with how fast the system can detect the recipient and route, that is a given- it is the fact that recipients respond before they could possibly have the required information even if the communication system was actually instantaneous. The only possible answer is that the system actually sends the comms back in time thereby cancelling the lag. If that is the in-universe explanation I'm fine with that, but I don't think it is.

Comment: @JamesChristopher, I believe (although I don't have sources to hand) that transporters were used because TOS was running out of budget and it was cheaper than building a shuttle set.  Once you got to STNG and they wanted to ground things a little more firmly they could not get rid of them.  Warp speed is based on a scientific leap concerning warping space time, no real base in science but they tried to discover a new special case rather than just shatter known laws.

Comment: @jwenting "the speed of light dictates the minimum delay between a signal being sent and received after all" Except when you have subspace.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure the Comm Badge is tied into the Universal Translator system/s.

The Universal Translator works by scanning the communicator's brain and mapping common concepts within the brain to a word for a similar concept the receiver can understand. This system works with no perceivable lag.

I would assume that when the Comm Badge is tapped it links its Universal Translator to the ship's communication network. When Riker decides to call Picard the word structure is in his mind, he then has to figure out how to move his mouth, lungs, and vocal cords. The Universal translator has that time to find a similar word to the English one Riker wants to use to a word in Picard's language. While the Comm system has that time to make the connection.
So the message they are sending is being transmitted before it leaves their mouths.