# What communications technology is used by Starfleet com badges?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

[A comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55156/why-is-there-no-combadge-lag-on-initiating-inter-personnel-comms/55167#comment107935_55167) was posted on [an answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/55167/3248) to [another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/55156/3248):

> there will always be a time delay caused, the speed of light dictates the minimum delay between a signal being sent and received after all.

This is in reference to Starfleet com badges. It made me wonder: what's to say com badges use conventional radio, rather than subspace communications? I haven't given it a lot of thought, but I was under the impression that com badges were subspace.

- Is it ever explicitly stated what communications technology is used "under the hood" by the com badges?

  - If it is explicitly stated, then what is it?
  - If it is not explicitly stated, then what can we derive from what we see on screen as well as other authoritative sources?
- Also, does this change over the course of the series?

Comment: When Janeway and Checotay are left behind by the voyager and Janeway gave her final speech to the crew - doesn't she do it using her combadge? If so, that would imply ftl since voyager is far away at that time.

Comment: @Einer You're right, I'm pretty sure they did. Of course, they *could* simply be using the combadge to relay to a subspace transmitter on the site (which could also have more power available). I'm more interested in the combadge itself.

Comment: Intraship communication is via conventional radio. Ship-to-ship or ship-to-shore communication is via (fictional) subspace radio allowing FTL conversations

Comment: @Richard Well, yes, subspace is fictional. So is Starfleet. :) If you can cite any sources for that comment though, it could probably make a good answer.

Comment: I'm at work. The answer will be in the "communication" section of the TNG Technical Manual but I've not got access to it from here.

Comment: @Valorum No, it's fine. I had completely forgot about this question. Thanks for the nudge.

Comment: @Valorum All I see is a straight line from 118k in October to 201k now. ;-) I wish I would get that kind of daily rep boost... :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's explicitly stated in both the TV series (Voy: "[Time and Again](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/103.htm)") and the [TNG Technical Manual](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation_Technical_Manual) that the communicator badges contain "subspace" technology allowing faster-than-light communication.

> **JANEWAY:** *We can assume that Voyager will be looking for a way to reach us. **I'll set my combadge to emit a subspace beacon...***

I've edited the relevant sections in the picture below. There's also a handy constructor's guide showing the internal workings of the combadge.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From quick research this is what I've gathered the Star Trek Wikia memory alpha.

http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Combadge

I don't think it's clearly stated what form of communication it uses but there are some limitations to it such as range.

> The Starfleet combadge was a crystalline composite of gold,
>   microfilament, silicon, beryllium, and carbon-70. (TNG: "The Last
>   Outpost", "Time's Arrow"; VOY: "Hope and Fear") Due to the size of the
>   combadge, its working range was limited to five hundred kilometers,
>   although a starship could boost the signal to bridge larger distances.
>   (TNG: "11001001")

There's also no explicit mention of what's "under the hood" except other than what it's composed of and what the combadge can be modified / taken apart to achieve.

> In emergency situations, a combadge could be modified for use in other
>   applications. It could be converted into a subspace distress beacon,
>   or the tiny power cell could be extracted for other uses. (DS9: "Rocks
>   and Shoals") Lieutenant Worf used it to power a homemade field
>   generator for several seconds. (TNG: "A Fistful of Datas") In 2374,
>   Captain Kathryn Janeway of the USS Voyager was able to modify Seven of
>   Nine's Borg implants to escape the brig of the USS Dauntless using
>   pieces of her combadge. (VOY: "Hope and Fear") If the casing of the
>   combadge was ever cracked, an emergency distress signal was emitted,
>   mainly to help searchers locate victims. (TNG: "A Fistful of Datas";
>   VOY: "Time and Again") Combadges, when destroyed by an electrical
>   force, could cause damage to the wearer's clothing. (TNG: "Thine Own
>   Self")

As far as I can tell not much has changed in the combadges other than the designs.

2360's photo of combadge.

[image]

2370's photo of combadge

[image]

Comment: If you're going to quote heavily from memory-alpha it's considered polite to credit them.

Comment: Sorry didn't have my coffee forgot to link it XD

Comment: If it's limited to five hundred kilometers, ftl doesn't make much sense since even on its limits it would take 0.00167 secs for the signal to travel at lightspeed. There is little use in speeding that up, is there?

Comment: @Einer: well, subspace presumably bypasses most EM interference.

Comment: Still, 500 km ?   This can't be right.   Don't people talk to colleague far away on the planet and in orbit all the time?

Comment: @ThePopMachine But then it would be vulnerable to subspace interference - as we know there are ;-)

Comment: @ThePopMachine *"a starship could boost the signal to bridge larger distances"* A starship in orbit could presumably also act as a relay, and by using greater power and larger (higher gain) antennas could *probably* allow relaying over distances much greater than combadge-to-combadge communications would allow. That, at least, is probably 1930s technology, or earlier...

Comment: Geostationary orbit is 36,000 km for Earth and could easily be hundreds of thousands or millions of km for some planets.  I buy by this idea of "boosting the signal" at the receiving end.